# Why are FX options vols quoted in 25RR and 25BF terms instead of by strike like credit options?

Tags: options, volatility, fx

Credit options follow a quoting convention for the vols based on strike, which fits in neatly with the Black-Scholes framework.

So why are FX options vols quoted in terms of 25-delta Risk Reversals and Butterfly Spreads instead of directly by strike? If it's a short-hand to succinctly express the smile, then wouldn't a more legible way be to quote the 25-delta put, ATM and 25-delta call directly?

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: The RR gives a measure of the skew of the surface, and the fly the convexity. So while you could describe the surface in terms of three vol levels, it can easily be argued that describing it as atm, skew, and kurtosis/convexity, is just as good/better. It's just a convention.

Comment: Thanks, understood on the first point that RR gives a measure of the skew. But can you explain how BF gives a measure of the convexity? That I do not understand.

Comment: look at the finite difference formula for the second derivative [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Relation_with_derivatives) - long the points either side, and short 2x the central point.

Comment: Thanks, understood. One more point - am I right in saying that the ATM vol is the same as the DN vol? If yes, I don't understand why because I assumed the DN vol would apply to when the option delta is zero.

Comment: what does `DN` stand for? In the FX world people often care about the 50d options (or, for a straddle, zero delta), and these are talked about kind of in the same way that the ATM options are talked about in the equity world (note though that 50d is *not* ATM). If you're talking about the zero delta call/puts, then the vol here doesn't really make sense as it's not defined.

Comment: DN is this case is delta neutral, but I understand where I went wrong. Delta neutral doesn't mean that there is zero delta, but rather the delta of the call and put are equal (and opposite). Apols for the basic questions, making the jump (no pun intended) from credit to FX.

Comment: np. So delta neutral then is the 50d point as i described above.